# Angular reactive forms validate at least on field is not empty and 'lifecycle' of validator

Tags: angular, cross-validation, angular-reactive-forms

I want to validate form that at least one field is **not** empty - at least one field is filed. I created custom validator:

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

export const pfkValidator: ValidatorFn = (abstractControl: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
  let fg = (abstractControl as FormGroup);
  let isValid = false;
  Object.keys(fg.controls).forEach(
    field => {
      const ctrl = fg.get(field);
      if (ctrl instanceof FormControl) {
        console.log('ctrl value', ctrl.value);
        if (ctrl.value) {
          isValid = true;
        }
      }
    });

  if (isValid) return { 'valid': true }
  return null;
}
```

This is how form is initialized:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      Field1: [null],
      Field2: [null],
      Field3: [null],
      Field4: [null],
      Field5: [null],
      Field6: [null],
      Field7: [null],
      Field8: [null],
      Field9: [false],
      Field10: [false],
    }, { validators: pfkValidator });
}
```

Issue is when forms loads, validation is activated for every field, which takes quite a time. My form has 10 fields and I have logged 10x10 inputs in console.

[image: part of the log]

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: can you share how you have initialized your form?

Comment: @OwenKelvin sure, I updated post with form initialization.

Comment: These fields, why not use a dynamic FormArray?

Comment: Not sure that it will make and difference.

Comment: @Ivanhohoho, a validator must return null if is correct and anything if is not correct -you should change the last line:`if (isValid) return null else return { 'invalid': true }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is your implementation which shows 121 logs in the console

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b9vksn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

However in below implementation using `FormArrays` I have tried to reduce the running operations to avoid the loops [Demo using FormArrays](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jf6xgd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). The console now shows only 14 logs initially with 1 log per edit. You may even add `updateOn: 'blur'` to improve perfomance even further

```typescript
export const pfkValidator: ValidatorFn = (
  abstractControl: AbstractControl
): ValidationErrors | null => {
  console.log("ctrl value", abstractControl.value.join(""));
  if (abstractControl.value.join("") !== "") {
    return { atLeastOne: false };
  }
  return null;
};
```

This can be implemented like below

```
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  get fields() {
    return this.form.get("fields") as FormArray;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      fields: this.fb.array(
        [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, false, false],
        { validators: [pfkValidator] }
      )
    });
  }
}
```

and in the html

```html
<form [formGroup]='form'>
  <ng-container formArrayName='fields'>
    <input *ngFor="let control of fields.controls; let i = index" [formControlName]="i">
  </ng-container>

</form>
```